# Cloned element is not shown

Tags: javascript, html, clone

The following code should clone the given element and insert it after:

```
function cloneMore(element) {
    var newElement = element.cloneNode(true);
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
}
var addChoice = document.getElementById("add-choice")
addChoice.onclick = (function(){cloneMore(document.getElementById("choices").lastChild);})
```

The html looks like this:

```
<ul id="choices">
    <!-- form elements -->
</ul>
<p><a id="add-choice">Add another choice</a></p>
```

No exception is thrown and everything executes but I can not see the new element. Why?

Comment: console log it and see if it is even cloning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) picks all node types, not only Elements. So you are probably cloning a TextNode `\n`.

I guess that what you want is [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild).

```js
function cloneMore(element) {
  var newElement = element.cloneNode(true);
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
}
var addChoice = document.getElementById("add-choice")
addChoice.onclick = function() {
  var choices = document.getElementById("choices");
  cloneMore(choices.lastElementChild); // only Elements
  console.log('lastChild type : ', choices.lastChild.nodeName); 
}
```

```html
<ul id="choices">
  <li> choice </li>
</ul>
<p><a href="#" id="add-choice">Add another choice</a></p>
```